# use class from .jar in classpath

Tags: java, jar, cmd, swt, classpath

when I try to use some class, for example Layout, in *`swt.jar`* by cmd it complains me about not having it, this is the message error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Layout

The weird thing is, *`swt.jar`* is in `\ext` directory and my CLASSPATH is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\jre\lib\ext`

When I create a new project in eclipse there's no problem, all imports from this jar works fine, but on cmd I'm getting this error.

Help me please!

Answer (score 3):

You're learning a hard lesson: IDEs, including Eclipse, and Java EE app servers, like Tomcat, pay no attention to any environment variables like CLASSPATH.

I don't think a JAR like swt.jar belongs in the jre/lib/ext directory.  That should only be for JVM extensions from Oracle.

You should add that to your project /lib directory, along with all other 3rd party JARs, and set CLASSPATH in Eclipse and startup scripts properly.

Comment: I created a .jar file which uses swt.jar classes, when I execute this jar by cmd I'm getting this message:  Unable to access jar file
this 2 jar files are in my project /lib directory

Comment: I don't know if there's something wrong with my classpath  or my java installation too, because, for example when I use :javac MyClass.java there's nothing wrong, but after that if I use java MyClass I see this error message: "java.ClassNotFoundException: MyClass.java"

Comment: You need to learn how CLASSPATH works.  You need to set -cp with each individual JAR in the /lib directory separated with semi-colons on Windows.  Having them in the /lib directory is not enough.

Comment: You don't understand CLASSPATH; there's nothing wrong with your Java installation.

Comment: Ok, I see my problem is understanding how CLASSPATH works, but I think  (and insist) I still have a problem which is not related with that (maybe I should post it as another question).
The typical "Hello World" example, when I execute "javac HelloWorld.java" there is nothing wrong, but once .class file is created, I execute "java HelloWorld" but I see an error message saying the main class was not found (and I know HelloWorld is the main class, and it has the public static void main method)

Comment: Nope, you don't see the depth of your problem.  It has nothing to do with "Hello, World".

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the classpath till the `Jar File`, to use a class under that `Jar File`

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\jre\lib\ext\swt.jar
```

Just a suggestion: - Don't put your Jar files in the `ext` directory. Put it somewhere else.

As far as `Eclipse` is concerned, it does not uses the `System Classpath` set in the environment variable. You should put the `Jar File` in a `lib` directory under your project while using in Eclipse and add the `Jar File` to your BuildPath.